# How to configure vscode phpunit extension to run test with docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, phpunit, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to configure the vscode phpunit extension to run tests using docker-compose, which is located outside the project (laradock).

Structure of directories :

W:\MyLaravelProject

W:\Laradock

- docker-compose.yml

I have setup successfully PhpStorm. Anyway, I would like to switch on vscode but I cannot make it work.

Here is the launch command build by PhpStorm when I run the test :

```
[docker-compose://[W:\Laradock\docker-compose.yml]:php-fpm/]:php /var/www/MyLaravelProject/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --configuration /var/www/MyLaravelProject/phpunit.xml --filter "/(::testOne)( .*)?$/" Tests\Feature\FirstTest /var/www/MyLaravelProject/tests/Feature/FirstTest.php --teamcity
```

Here is my current vscode configuration :

```
    "phpunit.driverPriority": [
        "Docker",
        "Composer",
        "Path",
        "Phar",
        "Ssh",
        "GlobalPhpUnit"
    ],
    "phpunit.clearOutputOnRun": true,
    "phpunit.php": "docker-compose run php-fpm",
    "phpunit.phpunit": "/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit",
    "phpunit.paths": {
        "W:\\MyLaravelProject": "/var/www/MyLaravelProject"
    }
```

I expect the test to be run successfully using docker-compose.

- How to configure phpunit to use docker-compose ?
- How to specify another directory for docker-compose ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure in late with this answer but maybe I can help someone else.

I had a similar problem and I solved it using the [Remote - Containers](http://Name:%20Remote%20-%20Containers%20Id:%20ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers%20Description:%20Open%20any%20folder%20inside%20(or%20mounted%20into)%20a%20container%20and%20take%20advantage%20of%20Visual%20Studio%20Code%27s%20full%20feature%20set.%20Version:%200.134.1%20Publisher:%20Microsoft%20VS%20Marketplace%20Link:%20https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) extension.
It lets you use the phpunit command inside the container.

You just have to install it and attach the extension to the workspace container, then run tests normally.
You can also change settings only in the attached remote so you can adjust phpunit command path.